# How can I get the method name and parameters from a function expression?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, expression-trees

Example:

For reasons outside the scope of this example, I am forced to use this:

```
UserRepository repository = new UserRepository();
User user = (User)InvokeMethod(repository, "GetUserById", new object[]{2});

private object InvokeMethod(object source, string methodName, object[] parameters)
{
    Type sourceType = source.GetType();
    MethodInfo methodInfo = sourceType.GetMethod(methodName);
    return methodInfo.Invoke(source, parameters);            
}
```

However, I would much prefer something like this:

```
UserRepository repository = new UserRepository();
User user = GetUserById<User, UserRepository>(repository, m => m.GetUserById(2));
```

A wrapper could accomplish this. I started to build one, but got stuck. This is what I have:

```
public TUser GetUserById<TUser, TUserRepository>(TUserRepository repository, Expression<Func<TUserRepository, TUser>> repositoryFunc)
     where TUser : User
     where TUserRepoistory : UserRepository
{
    // How do I use the Expression to setup the next two statements?
    string methodName = ""; // should be "GetUserId"
    object[] params = null; // should be "object[] { 2 }"

    TUser user = (TUser)InvokeMethod(repository, methodName, parameters);
}
```

Keep in mind I am forced to use the InvokeMethod method. I cannot simply invoke the Func.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gets complex depending on whether the arguments are literals, captured variables, etc - and whether they are `ref`, `out`, etc.  You might want to look at the implementation in protobuf-net.Extensions, [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net.Extensions/ServiceModel/Client/ProtoClientExtensions.cs), which has code to all of this - in particular the `ResolveMethod` method.

The `MethodInfo` is simple - just cast `Body` to `MethodCallExpression` and obtain the `.Method.Name` - but for the parameters it recursively calls into `Evaluate` - this allows expressions like `SomeMethod(123, x, y.Foo.Bar)` to work, where `123` is a literal, `x` is a captured variable, and `y.Foo.Bar` is something hanging *off* a captured variable.